# Magento 2 page selector bug?

Tags: magento, configuration, selector

When selecting a page in product's configurations, the whole page freezes

See below image:

[image]

Comment: You must be getting some error in the console or in the response of the request to server. I would suggest checking that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you press F5? If it is not related to any events, then it is possibly correlated with invalidated caches. Could be your browser issue?
You might want to update everything else to see if the same issue occurs.